# How can I apply a vertical scrollbar to a div with a percentage height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've come across numerous question of the similar nature but my situation is a bit different; my outer container is height 100% instead of a fixed height.

I have a bunch of `div`s inside a container. They overflow and I want to have a scrollbar to allow scrolling.

This is exactly what I want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/jcjw2jmo/

Except, the link I posted has a fixed `height: 200px;`. I want to have a percentage height instead.

I've tried setting a percentage `height` and `max-height` with no luck. Here's my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/k52eh0xr/

How do I get both the fiddles to have the same behaviour but with using percentages instead?

Thanks so much

PS. I know this can be done using Javascript/jQuery but I am looking for a CSS-only solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need set your `html` and `body` tag with `height:100%` so you can use percent like you want

```
html, body {height:100%}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k52eh0xr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having relates mostly to using percentage heights in CSS.

If you're going to use a percentage height on a child element, you need to [specify the percentage height for *all parent elements*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276) up to and including the `body` and root elements (`html`).

Try this in your code:

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
/* NEW */
html, body { 
    height: 100%; /* necessary when using percentage heights within body
                     on non-absolutely positioned children (such as .outer)
                     more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276 */ 
    overflow: hidden; /* prevent vertical scrollbar on browser window,
                         in conformance with demos posted in question */
} 

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%; /* ADJUSTED */
    /* max-height: 10%; REMOVED */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 300px;
}

.inner {
    /* height: 10%; REMOVED
    max-height: 10%; REMOVED */
}

.item {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/k52eh0xr/5/